# Copy Files via FTP and using powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, ftp

I am using jenkins to implement CI and am successful in publishing the files to a build server. 
However , deployment to App Server isnt working as the FTP plugin is only copying folders, not files.
So I am writing a powershell script to copy files via FTP.

I have managed to write this so far with help of googling around:

```
## Automate FTP uploads
## Go to destination
cd C:\TrashFolder
$location = Get-Location
"We are here: $location"
## Get files
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse   
## Get ftp object
$ftp_client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$ftp_address = "ftp://MyUserName:MyPassword@ftp://IPAddress"
## Make uploads
foreach($file in $files)
  {

    $directory = "";
    $source = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file;
    if ($File.DirectoryName.Length -gt 0)
     {
        $directory = $file.DirectoryName.Replace($Location,"")
     }
   $Directory += "/";
   $FtpCommand = $ftp_address + $directory + $file

   $uri = New-Object System.Uri($FtpCommand)
   "Command is " + $uri + " file is $source"
    $ftp_client.UploadFile($uri, $source)
 }
```

but am getting this exception

`Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote name could not be resolved: 'ftp'"
At C:\DeployScripts\FileUpload.ps1:26 char:5
+     $ftp_client.UploadFile($uri, $source)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException`

help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: The error seems with the address resolution. Try a ping $ftp_address

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like the $ftp address string needs some fixing for starters.

```
"ftp://MyUserName:MyPassword@server"
```

Example:

```
"ftp://Nick:MyPassword@myftpserver.net"
```

There shouldnt be a 2nd ftp:// in front of the server IP/Name. See if that helps

Comment: I have tested your code with the suggested correction and its working for me now, Can you amend your question with the updated code you are using and if the error message has changed.

Comment: `Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At C:\DeployScripts\FileUpload.ps1:26 char:5
+     $ftp_client.UploadFile($uri, $source)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException`

Comment: The problem I have is the username has a backslash in it "\" and I'm getting an error on the URI parse.

Comment: Ok that will be problem number 2, I googled it. Apparently you need to escape backslashes in the username by adding a second backslash so \ becomes \\ Try that

Comment: My username doesnt have a backslash.
The value of URI is ftp://Username:password@4NumberIPAddress/Views

Comment: Have you tried uploading to the root of the FTP, Have you tried using the hostname instead of IP address. Your code works fine when i run it, so it might be something environment based.

Comment: @Nick Im getting this error now :The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode